# Predict probability of predicted class

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

ml beginner here.

I have a dataset containing the GPA, GRE, TOEFL, SOP&LOR Ranking(out of 5)etc. (all numerical) , and a final column that states whether or not they were admitted to a university(0 or 1), which is what we'll use as y_train. 
I'm supposed to not just classify the predicted labels, but also calculate the probability of each person getting admitted.

edit: so from the from the first comment, I built a Logistic Regression model, and with some googling I found 'predict_proba' from sklearn and tried implementing it. There werent any syntactical errors but the code values given by predict_proba were horribly wrong.

Link: https://github.com/tarunn2799/gre-pred/blob/master/GRE%20Admission%20Probability-%20Extraaedge.ipynb

please help me finding where I've gone wrong, and also tips to reduce the loss

thank you!

Comment: It's most about trying out different model and find the best one. As it is binary classification problem the first try will Logistic regression.If you do get good result you can apply some feature selection. Then also try other model like Random Forest and SVM. You can use confusion metrix after every model and evaluate the model performance.

Comment: https://github.com/tarunn2799/gre-pred the model I've created so far is here. I don't know where I went wrong but the values for predict_proba are horribly wrong

Comment: https://github.com/DataPsycho/Py-DS-References/blob/master/04-ML-Ref/02-LogRM-Ref/01-Log-Hands-On.ipynb  Try using confusing metrics to check your accuracy. The note book from a one line course I took.

Answer (score 0):

I read your notebook, but I'm confused why you think the `predict_proba` are horribly wrong.. 
Is the predict accuracy not good, or the format of `predict_proba` not as you expected?

You could use `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score()`, `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix()` to check your predict label, or use `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score()` to check the result of `predict_proba`. Check both train & text parts are better.

I think the format of `predict_proba` is correct, or maybe you could try the `predict_log_proba()` to calculate the log probability?

Hope this could help you.